# Rewrite rails "where" query to work with heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Evening all,

I have this query running just fine on my local machine,

```
@articles = Article.where(category: "news").includes(:pictures)
```

however when using this on Heroku, the query doesn't populate the page, is this an issue with needing to rewrite the query or is it a Heroku issue? ( p.s i have restarted heroku and run all migrations)

Any tips would be great, thanks in advance, Andy

Comment: Is there data to support it? My suggestion would be to try messing around with `heroku run console`, try things like `Article.where(category: "news")` and check the results. Add on the includes and so forth from there to see what works.

Comment: Hi Agmcleod, I have just created one post, under news, and also changed the query to; Article.find_all_by_category("News"), which found the post correctly, however this hasn't worked again in heroku, any suggestions?

Comment: So in heroku it just returns nil? If that's the case, and the post comes up when you call `Article.all`, then I'm not sure. Usually when a query doesn't work in production, I would recommend to double check the data exists in the production db, so the heroku database.

Comment: `'news' != 'News'` so maybe you should try `.where(category: 'News')`.

Comment: yes Mu you were right!, silly boy eventually I used Article.find_all_by_category("News"), put it as an answer and ill tick n vote, cheers everyone, Andy

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your development database (probably SQLite) is not case sensitive, while Postgres on Heroku is.

When I want Heroku to be case insensitive, I use something like this:

```
where("upper(category) like ?", "NEWS")
```

This is why it's a best practice to keep your dev environment as close as possible to your production environment.